# Cannot use Trace.WriteLine in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, trace

In Windows Store application I can use:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test");
```

But replacing `Debug` with `Trace` gives the following error: `CS0103: The name 'Trace' does not exist in the current context` How can I fix this?

Comment: WinRT doesn't have `Trace`, and it lacks trace listeners. Debug.WriteLine is the best you can do without resorting to something 3rd party like [metrolog](https://github.com/mbrit/metrolog).

Comment: @vcsjones you should elevate the comment to an answer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

WinRT doesn't have Trace, and it lacks trace listeners. `Debug.WriteLine` is the best you can do without resorting to something 3rd party like [metrolog](https://github.com/mbrit/metrolog).

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is lots of existing code referring to `Trace.` you could alias `Debug` as `Trace` with

```
using Trace = System.Diagnostics.Debug;
```

Comment: Yes this work. No the behavior is not what is expected. Not excellent. Acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting the Target and Min version respectively to Fall Creators Update (build 16299) and November Update (build 10586). A too early Min version (15063) seems not to contain Trace.

Maybe I misunderstand about UWP/WinRT from the accepted answer that warns about missing trace listeners (maybe it was true at the time of asking/answering). But by nugetting the package System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener I got a listener that dumps traces into a file.

Comment: Could you please share a sample of your solution? I'm unable to get it to create the file using TextWriterTraceListener, and I'm on a much higher build number than yours.